# Converting SQL query to Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a very large query and many more that are even bigger.

I've tried to convert it to work with Laravel's DB class except it's not returning anything.

Is there something that can do this automatically?  Like a converter?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 
cases.id
FROM cases 
LEFT JOIN cases_cstm ON cases.id = cases_cstm.id_c 
JOIN cases_contacts_1_c ON cases.id = cases_contacts_1_c.cases_contacts_1cases_ida AND cases_contacts_1_c.deleted = 0 
JOIN contacts ON cases_contacts_1_c.cases_contacts_1contacts_idb = contacts.id AND contacts.deleted = 0 
LEFT JOIN contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c ON contacts.id = contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c.contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1contacts_ida 
LEFT JOIN pal_policy_adviser_list ON contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c.contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1pal_policy_adviser_list_idb = pal_policy_adviser_list.id 
LEFT JOIN huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c ON cases.id = huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c.huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1cases_idb AND huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c.deleted = 0 
LEFT JOIN huge__insurance_carriers ON huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c.huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1huge__insurance_carriers_ida = huge__insurance_carriers.id AND huge__insurance_carriers.deleted = 0 
LEFT JOIN products_cases_1_c ON cases.id = products_cases_1_c.products_cases_1cases_idb 
LEFT JOIN products ON products_cases_1_c.products_cases_1products_ida = products.id 
WHERE cases.deleted = 0 
AND contacts.id = 'b8a00721-40f1-7801-b4b9-50ce152ce2ec' 
AND ((cases.status = 'Entered') or (cases.status = 'Submitted') or (cases.status = 'Approved') or (cases.status = 'Issued') or (cases.status = 'Gathering_Medical_Information') or (cases.status = 'Awaiting_Carrier_Offers') or (cases.status = 'All_Offers_In') or (cases.status = 'Informal_Entered') or (cases.status = 'Await_Del_Req')) GROUP BY cases.id ORDER BY cases_cstm.insured_name_c ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Laravel query

```
DB::table('cases')
        ->leftJoin('cases_cstm', 'cases.id', '=', 'cases_cstm.id_c')
        ->join('cases_contacts_1_c', 'cases.id', '=', 'cases_contacts_1_c.cases_contacts_1cases_ida')
        ->join('contacts', 'cases_contacts_1_c.cases_contacts_1contacts_idb', '=', 'contacts.id')
        ->leftJoin('contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c', 'contacts.id', '=', 'contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c.contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1contacts_ida')
        ->leftJoin('pal_policy_adviser_list', 'contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1_c.contacts_pal_policy_adviser_list_1pal_policy_adviser_list_idb', '=', 'pal_policy_adviser_list.id')
        ->leftJoin('huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c', 'cases.id', '=', 'huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c.huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1cases_idb')
        ->leftJoin('huge__insurance_carriers', 'huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1_c.huge__insurance_carriers_cases_1huge__insurance_carriers_ida', '=', 'huge__insurance_carriers.id')
        ->leftJoin('products_cases_1_c', 'cases.id', '=', 'products_cases_1_c.products_cases_1cases_idb')
        ->leftJoin('products', 'products_cases_1_c.products_cases_1products_ida', '=', 'products.id')
        ->where('contacts.id', '=', 'b8a00721-40f1-7801-b4b9-50ce152ce2ec')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Entered')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Submitted')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Approved')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Issued')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Gathering_Medical_Information')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Awaiting_Carrier_Offers')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'All_Offers_In')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Informal_Entered')
        ->orWhere('cases.status', '=', 'Await_Del_Req');
        ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried a less ambitious conversion, like starting with a less sophisticated query and building up? Also what query does that actually run?

Comment: You can also just use the `DB::select()` method to run the query as-is.

Comment: You need either `where(function($q){$q->where(...)->orWhere(...)...})` to wrap those wheres in parentheses OR better use `whereIn('column', [...])` for all those statuses.

Comment: @deczo I've tried that and it still didn't work.  Could you write an example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$statuses = [...]; // array of statuses to compare

DB::table('cases')
  // all your joins
  ->where('contacts.id', '=', 'b8a00721-40f1-7801-b4b9-50ce152ce2ec')
  ->whereIn(cases.status', $statuses)
  ->get(['cases.id']);
```

or (really, don't, just as an example):

```
DB::table('cases')
  // all your joins
  ->where('contacts.id', '=', 'b8a00721-40f1-7801-b4b9-50ce152ce2ec')
  ->where(function($q) { // this will wrap all those OR WHERE clauses in AND ( .. )
     $q->where(...)
       // all the orWheres
       ->orWhere(...);
  })
  ->get(['cases.id']);
```

Also, use `DB::getQueryLog()` after that to get the array of the queries, that were run by Laravel.